# Show/Hide a button if a custum field is display

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a problem in a checkout page of my website (wordpress based).
I have two kind of products and for each one, during checkout, I created custom fields to collect specific informations. With conditional rules (by plugin) some fields show up only if a list of specific option is checked.
When they are hidden, analysing the code, I've this situation:

```
<div class="form-row form-row-wide thwcfe-html-field-wrapper thwcfe-conditional-field" id="stud_no_req_field" data-name="stud_no_req" data-rules="[[[[{&quot;operand_type&quot;:&quot;field&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;value_eq&quot;,&quot;operand&quot;:[&quot;student&quot;]}]]]]" data-rules-action="show" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

When they are showing up, style attribute change in "block".

At the end of the page, I also have a button to submit the order.

```
<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Associati" data-value="Associati">Associati</button>
```

I'm looking for a script that hides this button if custom file above has "display:block" and viceversa (show button if div has "display:none").

I've tried with this script (in checkout page), but nothing happens:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($("#stud_no_req_field").style.display == "block")
{
    $("#place_order").style.display = "none";  
}
else
{
    $("#place_order").style.display = "block";
}
});
</script>
```

I also need that this script is automatic (no click needed) and listens to any automatic change of div style (inside html tag).

Thank you very much!!! You are my angels!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong code. You should do

```
$("#place_order")[0].style.display = 'none'; // I added [0]
```

Or use jQuery API (https://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$("#place_order").css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: May you write the complete script? I've tried to change both line with first correction and, later, with second one. No one works for me :(

Comment: I also recive an error message: "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function".

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: I've included jQuery. WordPress has its own version of the jQuery library (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1). I've enqueued the script via function.php file of child theme. 'wp_enqueue_script("jquery");' This particular copy of jQuery is in compatibility mode by default. The typical $ shortcut for jQuery doesn't work, so it doesn't conflict with any other JavaScript libraries. We have to use jQuery instead $.Now I have no more errors during inspection, but script doesn't work. I have no ideas. Maybe elements have style attribute in html tag? May elements have a class attribute?